# VB.NET Multi-Image loading with loop

Tags: vb.net

I hope you can help me.

Let me explain, I try to make a timer load the same image every time, but with a modified link:

https://hypixel.maxkorlaar.com/player/069a79f444e94726a5befca90e38aaf5/image/3d/AddingNumberHere/6.png

Where there is "addingnumberhere" I would like to make it possible to add a +1 to each loop up to 360 (currently that number indicates the degrees in which the image is pointing)

Every time a number is added we create a "3D in 2D" effect. I don't know if I can explain myself

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    Try
        PictureBox1.Image = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(New IO.MemoryStream(New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadData("https://hypixel.maxkorlaar.com/player/069a79f444e94726a5befca90e38aaf5/image/3d/" + 1 & "/6.png")))

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your code using the [PictureBox.Load](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.picturebox.load) or [LoadAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.picturebox.loadasync) methods to download and show and Image referenced by an `Uri`.

Add a counter for the Timer ticks and reset it when it reaches the maximum value:

```
Dim imageMax As Integer = 360
Dim imageNumber As Integer = 0
Dim urlBase As String = $"https://hypixel.maxkorlaar.com/player/069a79f444e94726a5befca90e38aaf5/image/3d/"

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    imageNumber = If(imageNumber < imageMax, imageNumber + 1, 0)
    Dim url As String = urlBase & $"{imageNumber}/6.png"
    PictureBox1.Load(url)
End Sub
```

If you need to show these images more than once, it's probably a good idea to download them and use the cached collection of Images, as [djv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56838180/7444103) is suggesting.

---

Sample process to download asynchronously the Images before starting the Timer:

Add these lines to the `Form.Load()` event or another event (as a `Button.Click()`) as the last ones. Note the **`async`**  keyword, you need to add it to the method declaration:

```
Dim images As List(Of Bitmap) = Nothing

Private Async Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' (...)
    images = Await LoadImagesAsync(urlBase, "6.png", imageMax)
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Dim imageMax As Integer = 360
Dim imageNumber As Integer = 0
Dim urlBase As String = $"https://hypixel.maxkorlaar.com/player/069a79f444e94726a5befca90e38aaf5/image/3d/"

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    imageNumber = If(imageNumber < imageMax, imageNumber + 1, 0)
    PictureBox1.Image = images(imageNumber)
End Sub

Friend Async Function LoadImagesAsync(baseUrl As String, imageFile As String, numOfImages As Integer) As Task(Of List(Of Bitmap))
    Dim urls = Enumerable.Range(0, numOfImages).
        Select(Function(img)
                   Return New UriBuilder(
                       Path.Combine(baseUrl, img.ToString(), imageFile)).Uri.ToString()
               End Function).ToList()

    Return Await DownloadImagesAsync(urls)
End Function

Private Async Function DownloadImagesAsync(urls As List(Of String)) As Task(Of List(Of Bitmap))
    Dim getImage As Func(Of String, Task(Of Bitmap)) =
        Async Function(url)
            Using client As New WebClient()
                Dim buffer As Byte() = Await client.DownloadDataTaskAsync(url)
                Using ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(buffer)
                    ms.Position = 0
                    Return New Bitmap(ms, True)
                End Using
            End Using
        End Function

    Dim result = Await Task.WhenAll(urls.Select(Function(url) getImage(url)).ToArray())
    Return result.ToList()
End Function
```

Comment: thanks, it works! How can I make the image change faster?

Comment: Set the Timer interval to a lower value? I depends on how fast you want to replace the images and the download speed of that site/your internet connection. See also what [djv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56838180/7444103) suggested. If you cannot download the images fast enough, download them all first. I'll add a sample code for this.

Answer (score 0):

It's just an issue with string concatenation. When you create the path

```
"https://hypixel.maxkorlaar.com/player/069a79f444e94726a5befca90e38aaf5/image/3d/" + 1 & "/6.png"
```

you use operators `+` and `&`, when only `&` should be used for strings. But it's sometimes better to use string interpolation. Here is a complete working example (along with your enabled Timer) using the `&` operator.

```
Static counter As Integer = 1
Dim path = $"https://hypixel.maxkorlaar.com/player/069a79f444e94726a5befca90e38aaf5/image/3d/{counter}/6.png"
PictureBox1.Image = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(New IO.MemoryStream(New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadData(path)))
counter = (counter + 1) Mod 360
```

This works, but if you are modifying the Bitmap so frequently, it may be a better idea to cache the images as you download them.

The below will download them all up front, and cache them. There is a few second delay at Form_Load but you could also run it asynchronously.

```
Private images As New List(Of Bitmap)()

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Static counter As Integer = 1
    PictureBox1.Image = images(counter)
    counter = (counter + 1) Mod 360
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim bag As New Concurrent.ConcurrentBag(Of Bitmap)()
    Parallel.For(
        1, 361,
        Sub(counter)
            Dim path = $"https://hypixel.maxkorlaar.com/player/069a79f444e94726a5befca90e38aaf5/image/3d/{counter}/6.png"
            bag.Add(New System.Drawing.Bitmap(New IO.MemoryStream(New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadData(path))))
        End Sub)
    images = bag.ToList()
End Sub
```